# filter return combined matches

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, filter

```
arr = [{name: "tom", tools:["spanner", "hammer", "screwdriver"]}, 
{name: "john", tools:["Mallet", "hammer", "screwdriver"]},
{name: "phil", tools:["Mallet", "Drill", "screwdriver"]}]


private filterObjectArray(arr: any, filterArr: any): any {
  return arr.filter((el: any) =>
    filterArr.some(
      (f: any) =>
        el.tools.toString()?.toLowerCase().indexOf(f.name?.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    )
  );
 }
```

My filter is similar to the above, at the moment if my filter returned `filterArr = [{name: "screwdriver"}, {name: "hammer"}]` then all objects would be returned as they all have at least one match in `screwdriver`.

However, how do I make it that only objects that has both filter properties display e.g. in the above I expect only the two objects `tom` and `john` return as they both have a `screwdriver` and `hammer`, whereas `phil` only has a `screwdriver` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in JS. You can use `every` here to check if that every filter is included in the tools array

```js
let arr = [{name: "tom", tools:["spanner", "hammer", "screwdriver"]}, 
{name: "john", tools:["Mallet", "hammer", "screwdriver"]},
{name: "phil", tools:["Mallet", "Drill", "screwdriver"]}]

let filterArr = [{name: "screwdriver"}, {name: "hammer"}]

let res = arr.filter(({tools}) => filterArr.every(({name}) => tools.includes(name)))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: I forgot to use "every"!

Answer (score 0):

You can use every instead of the includes(index >= 0)

It means

## everything match then true otherwise false

```
private filterObjectArray(arr: any, filterArr: any): any {
    return arr.filter((el: any) => filterArr.every((f: any) => el.tools.includes(f.name)))
}
```